# The Select Tool doesn't seem to be shrinking or expanding an object on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hi guys, 
I'm a bit stuck here. 
The Select Tool doesn't seem to shrink or enlarge objects. I'm using Illustrator CS6.
It only seems to just move it around. 
Please help, thanks x

Answer (score 0):

You just have the "show bounding box" option disabled:

[image]

Comment: Awww thats great, thank you ever so much xxxx